# Get pathinfo from an open file handle

Tags: php

I'm reading data from a file and need to run checks on its extension

I opened the file handle with fopen and given the handle to pathinfo()

```
$handle2 = fopen('files/ppGM.txt', 'r');
$fileinfo = pathinfo($handle2);
```

I need the array of informations from path info but the functions requires the first parameter to be string:

> Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /home/kroman02/public_www/p1tma/index.php on line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) as it suggests - works with the path of a file and not a file handle.  So you would usually use something like...

```
$fileName = 'files/ppGM.txt';
$handle2 = fopen($fileName, 'r');
$fileinfo = pathinfo($fileName);
```

and this would result with `$fileinfo` containing...

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => files
    [basename] => ppGM.txt
    [extension] => txt
    [filename] => ppGM
)
```